# How to create a reaction norm (joining means by line) in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I have the following data, where I want to plot "values" for species 1 and 2 across two time points (t1, t2). I want to create a plot where the raw values of each species is visible using geom_points (different colors). Also, I want to display the mean using a larger size of the same color. 
For a given species, I want to connect the mean at t1 and t2 (also called reaction norms). So in this example, the line for species 1 should slope upward, and that of species 2 should remain unchanged.

I have attempted the basic ggplot2 but I do not know how to add the lines and display the mean in larger size. Also, for some reason "fill" is not generating different colours.

```
time <- c("t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2")
species <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
value <- c(1,2,3,11,12,13,4,5,6,11,12,13)

df <- data.frame(time, species,value)
df$time <- as.factor(df$time)
df$species <- as.factor(df$species)

ggplot(df,aes(x=time, y=value, fill = species)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, position = "dodge") + 
  stat_summary(geom="errorbar", fun.data= mean_cl_boot, width = 0.1, size = 0.2, col = "grey57") + 
  ylab("Fitness")
```

Comment: Errorbars have a color, not a fill, which is why you don't see a color change

Comment: Could you either sketch or post an example of what you're trying to get? I'm having trouble picturing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=time, y=value, color = species)) + # Change fill to color
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, position = "dodge") + 
  stat_summary(
    geom="errorbar", 
    fun.data= mean_cl_boot, 
    width = 0.1, size = 0.2, col = "grey57") + 
  # Lines by species using grouping
  stat_summary(aes(group = species), geom = "line", fun.y = mean) +
  ylab("Fitness")
```

If you want two errorbars you can add the `group` of the line summary into the ggplot aesthetics.

Comment: Thanks! I still don't get how to add different summary bars to each points. I tried `ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value, color = species, group = species)` but it doesnt do the job

Comment: That's odd, can you share the full code (maybe for just the errorbar plot given the dataframe). I get 4 errorbars in total when putting species in the ggplot aesthetics.

Comment: I just realized my error. In the code, I added a extra bracket. One more question..if I want to increase the size of the "mean" of the points do I simply add "size" to the stat_summary code?

Comment: You currently don't have mean points. You can change the `"errorbar"` to `"pointrange", fatten=10` to get errorbars with a large center point.

Comment: For the lines, yes it would just be a size

Answer (score 3):

If I'm following what you're trying to get, this should work with some tweaks as you see fit. The basic trick is setting up the `aes` in each layer. I set `color`/`group` in each layer individually, because otherwise I had trouble getting the path to show up *between* times rather than *within* times.

So the first summary is the path between groups. The second is the errorbar; as I noted above, this has a color, not a fill. You'd previously set color outside of the `aes`, making the errorbars all gray regardless of whether you'd mapped color to a variable. The mean points have a bigger size (4) than the regular points (2).

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = species), fun.y = mean, geom = "path") +
  stat_summary(aes(color = species), fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1) +
  stat_summary(aes(color = species), fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(color = species), size = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>